# Using Knockout.js how to extract selected items from a multiselect dropdown list in an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to extract selected items from a multi-select Select HTML element when these elements are embedded in table rows?

Please check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exjt5pus/3/)

How can I list the selected country ids for each row when using Knockout.js? How do I use the selectedValues option for each row?

```
<div id="CountryList" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px">
    <table id="Countries">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Line No.</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: countryLines">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: lineNumber"></td>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: $root.availableCountries, optionsValue: 'countryId', optionsText: 'countryName'" multiple="true"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: showSelectedCountries">Show Selected Countries (console log)</button>

function CountryLine(lineNumber, initialCountry) {
    var self = this;
    self.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    self.country = ko.observable(initialCountry);
}

function CountryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.countryLines = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Get audit cycles
    self.availableCountries = [{
        countryId: "1",
        countryName: "Canada"
    }, {
        countryId: "2",
        countryName: "Brasil"
    }, {
        countryId: "3",
        countryName: "Australia"
    }];


    self.countryLines.push(new CountryLine("Line 1", "1"));
    self.countryLines.push(new CountryLine("Line 2", "2"));

    // Operations
    self.showSelectedCountries = function () {

        var self = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < self.countryLines().length; i++) {

            var lineNumber = self.countryLines()[i].lineNumber;
            console.log(lineNumber);
            // var selectedCountries = self.countryLine()[i].country; Question: how to extract selected countries for each row?

        }
    } // end showSelectedCountries


} // end self.scheduleAudits

ko.applyBindings(new CountryViewModel());
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little unclear on what you're asking, are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/o6qpqkmd/ ?

Comment: @akrist Thank you this is exactly what I'm after. If you would like to answer the question then I'll be able to give you an up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Knockout using the [selectedOptions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) binding. Check out this JSFiddle for information:

http://jsfiddle.net/o6qpqkmd/2/

Update your CountryLine object to include the necessary array:

```
function CountryLine(lineNumber, initialCountry) {
    var self = this;
    self.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    self.selectedCountries = ko.observableArray([initialCountry]);
}
```

And add it to the binding in the view:

```
<td>
    <select data-bind="options: $root.availableCountries, optionsValue: 'countryId', optionsText: 'countryName', selectedOptions: selectedCountries" multiple="true"></select>
</td>
```

Essentially the selectedOptions binding allows to to store the selected values in an Observable Array on the model.